# .NET COM component with ISDispatch interface does not work from IE10 JavaScript having .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, com, frameworks

I apologize for this (so long) title but I needed to fill all the relevant topics there in order to better clarify my post.

The thing is, as the title says, I have a running application that uses a .NET (C#) COM component accessible from Internet Explorer via JavaScript using late binding. The .NET COM component exports InterfaceIsDispatch in order to have some events that are thrown from the component to the JavaScript world, among other interface to access the component from JavaScript.

The **application has been working perfectly with this environment**:

- Compiled and deployed with **Visual Studio 2010** and Setup MSI.
- **.NET Framework 4.0**.
- **Internet Explorer 10**

The **problem** appeared when my machine was **updated to .NET Framework 4.5.1**. The **events** normally obtained from IsDispatch interface have **stopped to work**.

Here I write the involved code (nothing special, the normal way of exposing .NET code to COM).

A class that is going to be COM registered:

```
[Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")]
[ProgId("NPlayer")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
 ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComEvents))]
public partial class NPlayer : UserControl, IExposedMembers, IObjectSafety
{
  [...]
}
```

The way of making InterfaceIsDispatch:

```
[Guid("YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IComEvents
{
  [...]

  [DispId(4)]
  void CloseEvent();

  [...]
}
```

The way of sending CloseEvent events:

```
[...]

[ComVisible(false)]
public delegate void CloseEventHandler();

public event CloseEventHandler CloseEvent;

[...]

if (CloseEvent != null)
  CloseEvent();

[...]
```

The way of receiving the COM events from JavaScript (actually the JavaScript is embedded in a GWT interface but I usualy use a dummy HTML code for simplyfing the tests):

```
<body>

[...]

<object id="NPlayer" name="NPlayer" classid="CLSID:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            codebase="NPlayerDeployer.cab#version=5,1,5,0" width="0" height="0">/object>

[...]

<script for="NPlayer" event="CloseEvent()" language="javascript">
  alert("CloseEvent received!")
</script>

[...]

</body>
```

**Anybody knows some information about this issue?** Googling for a solution has not given me any results. I am now trying to upgrade myself to Visual Studio 2013 (that supports .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.5.1) but the results are even worse, Internet Explorer 10 crashes with the new deployment (I suppose this is another post).

Please some help would be very appreciated.

Best wishes,

Domingo.

Comment: You should post some code, a small but relevant fragment.

Comment: Yeah your right, sorry about that. I suppose I did not because may be I was waiting for some obvious answer like "Yes, .NET COM components does not work with JavaScript in .NET Framework 4.5.1".. ;) Now the code is in my post.

Comment: Does `IComEvents` have `[ComVisible(true)]`? Also, I don't see `[ComDefaultInterface]` on `NPlayer`, have you got one?

Comment: mmm... no, do you think is it necessary? It has worked in this way until now..

Comment: Neither [ComDefaultInterface], I used [ComSourceInterfaces] instead...

Comment: I haven't dealt with a case like yours, but I think you should try both attributes. Put `ComDefaultInterface` like this: `[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IExposedMembers))]`. `ComSourceInterfaces` should remain there, too. `IComEvents` should have `[ComVisible(true)]`, same as `IExposedMembers`.

Comment: Don't forget to do `RegAsm.exe` to update the interop registration.

Comment: Thanks Noseratio!! Although everything was OK with my .NET COM component finally...

Answer (score 0):

**I resolved my problem** and I would like to write it here because my analysis was wrong so the title of the problem does not fit with my real problem!

My oversight came with the fact of I am using a .NET COM component and the application error was reproduced when I upgraded the version of .NET Framework to 4.5.1.

I thought the problem was with the C# code, but the real problem was with the GWT (JavaScript) code. After receiving the event from the .NET COM component, my code calls some other JavaScript code in order to propagate the event to the interface side, and there I found a bad using of the scopes in JavaScript, that appeared with the new release of .NET Framework! Well, this is not the subject of this post so I am not going on with this explanation.

Summarizing, **everything was OK with ISDispatch** interface and apart from that, my problem was fixed... ;)

Thanks Noseratio for your help!

Doming.